# c# How to get the content of an element in an XML file with the same tag but different attribute value?

Tags: c#, xml, winforms

This is part of the xml file. Say if I want to put all the value of the tag ns2:DAyOfWeek in 3 textboxs or just get the value of a specific one(for example: <ns2:DayOfWeek lang="zh-cn">). What should I do?

Part of the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>
   <ns2:GetFixtureByRaceResponse xmlns:ns2="http://www.hkjc.org.hk/Schema/CAP/IDASUBRS/FixtureLocal_v2" xmlns="http://www.hkjc.org.hk/Schema/CAP/Common_v2">
      <ns2:Return>
         <Code>0</Code>
         <EndOf_v2_0Elm />
      </ns2:Return>
      <ns2:RacingEvent>
         <ns2:Meeting meetingDate="2022-09-11+08:00" meetingID="MTG_20220911_0001" statusLastUpdated="2022-09-07T14:22:17.000+08:00" venueCode="ST">
            <ns2:MeetingInfo>
               <ns2:DayOfWeek lang="en-us">SUN</ns2:DayOfWeek>
               <ns2:DayOfWeek lang="zh-cn">星期日</ns2:DayOfWeek>
               <ns2:DayOfWeek lang="zh-hk">星期日</ns2:DayOfWeek>
               <ns2:Status>Defined</ns2:Status>
               <ns2:RaceSeason>22/23</ns2:RaceSeason>
               <ns2:NumOfRace>10</ns2:NumOfRace>
               <ns2:MeetingNo>01</ns2:MeetingNo>
               <ns2:TrackCode>TURF</ns2:TrackCode>
               <ns2:MeetingType>D</ns2:MeetingType>
               <ns2:ScheduledNumOfRace>10</ns2:ScheduledNumOfRace>
               <ns2:ActualNumOfRace>0</ns2:ActualNumOfRace>
               <ns2:EndOf_v2_0Elm />
            </ns2:MeetingInfo>
            <ns2:EndOf_v2_0Elm />
         </ns2:Meeting>
         <ns2:Race meetingID="MTG_20220911_0001" raceID="RACE_20220911_0010" raceNo="1" statusLastUpdated="2022-09-07T09:06:53.522+08:00">
            <ns2:RaceInfo>
               <ns2:Status>Declared</ns2:Status>
               <ns2:PostTime>2022-09-11T13:00:00.000+08:00</ns2:PostTime>
               <ns2:RaceName lang="en-us" seqNo="1">MOUNT PARKER HANDICAP</ns2:RaceName>
               <ns2:RaceName lang="zh-cn" seqNo="1">柏架山让赛</ns2:RaceName>
               <ns2:RaceName lang="zh-hk" seqNo="1">柏架山讓賽</ns2:RaceName>
               <ns2:Distance>1600</ns2:Distance>
               <ns2:NoOfDeclaredStarters>14</ns2:NoOfDeclaredStarters>
               <ns2:PrizeMoney prizeLevel="1">461700.00</ns2:PrizeMoney>
               <ns2:PrizeMoney prizeLevel="2">178200.00</ns2:PrizeMoney>
               <ns2:PrizeMoney prizeLevel="3">93150.00</ns2:PrizeMoney>
               <ns2:PrizeMoney prizeLevel="4">48600.00</ns2:PrizeMoney>
               <ns2:PrizeMoney prizeLevel="5">28350.00</ns2:PrizeMoney>
               <ns2:PrizeMoney prizeLevel="6">0.00</ns2:PrizeMoney>
               <ns2:PrizeMoney prizeLevel="7">0.00</ns2:PrizeMoney>
               <ns2:PrizeMoney prizeLevel="8">0.00</ns2:PrizeMoney>
               <ns2:PrizeMoney prizeLevel="9">0.00</ns2:PrizeMoney>
               <ns2:StakePrize>810000.00000</ns2:StakePrize>
               <ns2:RaceRemarks lang="en-us" seqNo="1" />
               <ns2:RaceRemarks lang="en-us" seqNo="2" />
               <ns2:RaceRemarks lang="en-us" seqNo="3" />
               <ns2:RaceRemarks lang="en-us" seqNo="4" />
               <ns2:RaceRemarks lang="en-us" seqNo="5" />
               <ns2:RaceRemarks lang="en-us" seqNo="6" />
               <ns2:RaceRemarks lang="en-us" seqNo="7" />
               <ns2:RaceRemarks lang="en-us" seqNo="8" />
               <ns2:RaceRemarks lang="zh-cn" seqNo="1" />
               <ns2:RaceRemarks lang="zh-cn" seqNo="2" />
               <ns2:RaceRemarks lang="zh-cn" seqNo="3" />
               <ns2:RaceRemarks lang="zh-cn" seqNo="4" />
               <ns2:RaceRemarks lang="zh-cn" seqNo="5" />
               <ns2:RaceRemarks lang="zh-cn" seqNo="6" />
               <ns2:RaceRemarks lang="zh-cn" seqNo="7" />
               <ns2:RaceRemarks lang="zh-cn" seqNo="8" />
               <ns2:RaceRemarks lang="zh-hk" seqNo="1" />
               <ns2:RaceRemarks lang="zh-hk" seqNo="2" />
               <ns2:RaceRemarks lang="zh-hk" seqNo="3" />
               <ns2:RaceRemarks lang="zh-hk" seqNo="4" />
               <ns2:RaceRemarks lang="zh-hk" seqNo="5" />
               <ns2:RaceRemarks lang="zh-hk" seqNo="6" />
               <ns2:RaceRemarks lang="zh-hk" seqNo="7" />
               <ns2:RaceRemarks lang="zh-hk" seqNo="8" />
               <ns2:Local>
                  <ns2:RaceIndex>1</ns2:RaceIndex>
                  <ns2:ClassCode>5</ns2:ClassCode>
                  <ns2:TrackCode>TURF</ns2:TrackCode>
                  <ns2:CourseCode>A</ns2:CourseCode>
                  <ns2:RatingRange>040-000</ns2:RatingRange>
                  <ns2:RatingType>H</ns2:RatingType>
                  <ns2:RaceType>H</ns2:RaceType>
                  <ns2:FieldSize>14</ns2:FieldSize>
                  <ns2:CupIndex />
                  <ns2:Footnotes lang="en-us" seqNo="1" />
                  <ns2:Footnotes lang="en-us" seqNo="2" />
                  <ns2:Footnotes lang="en-us" seqNo="3" />
                  <ns2:Footnotes lang="en-us" seqNo="4" />
                  <ns2:Footnotes lang="zh-hk" seqNo="1" />
                  <ns2:Footnotes lang="zh-hk" seqNo="2" />
                  <ns2:Footnotes lang="zh-hk" seqNo="3" />
                  <ns2:Footnotes lang="zh-hk" seqNo="4" />
                  <ns2:InternationalRaceIndicator>0</ns2:InternationalRaceIndicator>
                  <ns2:SectionNo>1</ns2:SectionNo>
                  <ns2:Going />
                  <ns2:SpecialRaceIndicator />
                  <ns2:SecDivDisplayIndicator>S</ns2:SecDivDisplayIndicator>
                  <ns2:StarterRemarks lang="en-us" seqNo="1" />
                  <ns2:StarterRemarks lang="en-us" seqNo="2" />
                  <ns2:StarterRemarks lang="en-us" seqNo="3" />
                  <ns2:StarterRemarks lang="en-us" seqNo="4" />
                  <ns2:StarterRemarks lang="en-us" seqNo="5" />
                  <ns2:StarterRemarks lang="en-us" seqNo="6" />
                  <ns2:StarterRemarks lang="en-us" seqNo="7" />
                  <ns2:StarterRemarks lang="en-us" seqNo="8" />
                  <ns2:StarterRemarks lang="zh-cn" seqNo="1" />
                  <ns2:StarterRemarks lang="zh-cn" seqNo="2" />
                  <ns2:StarterRemarks lang="zh-cn" seqNo="3" />
                  <ns2:StarterRemarks lang="zh-cn" seqNo="4" />
                  <ns2:StarterRemarks lang="zh-cn" seqNo="5" />
                  <ns2:StarterRemarks lang="zh-cn" seqNo="6" />
                  <ns2:StarterRemarks lang="zh-cn" seqNo="7" />
                  <ns2:StarterRemarks lang="zh-cn" seqNo="8" />
                  <ns2:StarterRemarks lang="zh-hk" seqNo="1" />
                  <ns2:StarterRemarks lang="zh-hk" seqNo="2" />
                  <ns2:StarterRemarks lang="zh-hk" seqNo="3" />
                  <ns2:StarterRemarks lang="zh-hk" seqNo="4" />
                  <ns2:StarterRemarks lang="zh-hk" seqNo="5" />
                  <ns2:StarterRemarks lang="zh-hk" seqNo="6" />
                  <ns2:StarterRemarks lang="zh-hk" seqNo="7" />
                  <ns2:StarterRemarks lang="zh-hk" seqNo="8" />
                  <ns2:EndOf_v2_0Elm />
               </ns2:Local>
               <ns2:WageringFieldSize>14</ns2:WageringFieldSize>
               <ns2:EndOf_v2_0Elm />
            </ns2:RaceInfo>
            <ns2:EndOf_v2_0Elm />
         </ns2:Race>
```

The code below is if I want to get a specific one.(it dosen't work)

```
 String URLString = "myXMLFile";
 XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(URLString);
 var dayOfWeek = new List<string>();

 while (reader.Read())
 {
    if (reader.Name.Equals("ns2:DayOfWeek") &&        
        reader.GetAttribute("lang").Equals("zh-cn"))
    {
        dayOfWeek.Add(ReadElementContentAsString());
        textBox1.Text = dayOfWeek[0];
    }
 }
```

The following is if I want to get all three DayOfWeek content.(it dosen't work, it only show the first one("SUN"), and it says indexOutOfBound)

```
while (reader.Read())
{
   if (reader.Name.Equals("ns2:DayOfWeek")))
   {
      dayOfWeek.Add(ReadElementContentAsString());
      textBox1.Text = dayOfWeek[0];
      textBox2.Text = dayOfWeek[1];
      textBox3.Text = dayOfWeek[2];
   }
}
```

Please help..thank you

Edited:
I figured it out..I did it by using MoveToNextAttribute() and MoveToElement()..Thank you...I really appreciate everyone's help

Comment: The first time the `if()` condition matches, the `dayOfWeek` list will only have the one first entry (at position `0`) it just added, so **of course** you get an indexOutOfBounds exception when trying to use indexes 1 and 2.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to parse the whole file, try this

```
    var dayOfWeek = new List<string>();
    using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(URLString))
    {
        var start = false;
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader.IsStartElement()
                && reader.Name == "ns2:DayOfWeek")
            {
                start = true;
                string val = reader.ReadString();

                //or
                //string theXmlString = reader.ReadOuterXml();
                //string val = XElement.Parse(theXmlString).Value;

                dayOfWeek.Add(val);
            }
            else if (start) break;  // if you don't want to go the whole file
        }
    }

                    textBox1.Text = dayOfWeek[0];
                    textBox2.Text = dayOfWeek[1];
                    textBox3.Text = dayOfWeek[2];
```

Comment: I do need to parse the whole file...I'm just using part of it to try things out first...But Thank you for the help